# hide the flash and other dirty effects that occur at page start when loading lots of JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm building a website, and I can notice that the more code I add in the JQuery body,

```
$(document).ready(function($){
   ...
});
```

the more annoying effects I have for the first second it takes to load the website. I can see all elements unstyled, then moving/being transformed until I reach the researched look and feel a second later.

It only takes a second by now, but I can't imagine going to production which such display bug at start.

Is anyone of you used to dealing with this effect ? What would you recommend ?

Thanks a lot guys ;)

UPDATE : I am not doing any ugly CSS through JQuery. I just happen to use a few different plugins. The most annoying one is the Jqx menu I am using. I can see the text unstyled before Jquery has finished transforming it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the content of the page then show it again after the page has finished loading.

Put this just after the opening body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('body').hide(); 
    $(window).load(function() { $('body').show(); }); 
</script>
```

Not saying this is the best way to do it but it should prevent the style flicker.

Comment: That would have been just nice. It works perfectly, but my menu doesn't look quite the same afterwards. No idea where that could come from.

Comment: @jeromeG Do you use some animation to show your menu? That could be causing a problem maybe.

Comment: $('body').css('visibility', 'hidden'); should do the job :). The hide function sets the 'display' to 'none' which prevents the layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS instead of jQuery to apply your initial styles!

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
you could try to smush your pictures via Yahoo SmushIt. 
This removes every unnecesseary bit of the image. 
Second you can compress your .js and .css file which adds more speed via http://jscompress.com/ and http://www.lotterypost.com/css-compress.aspx .

If you are using jQuery to style everything you change that immediately use CSS !

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `$(document).ready(...);` to assign classes, disable elements, move them around, etc then you may very well be doing it incorrectly. Wherever possible, assign the classes/styles in the HTML instead of doing it once the page has finished loading using Javascript. Rather than doing something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="exampleTextInput" name="example">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#exampleTextInput').addClass('exampleClass');
});
</script>
```

do the following instead:

```
<input type="text" id="exampleTextInput" name="example" class="exampleClass">
```